# Declaring XML namespaces for MathML

Tags: xml, xhtml, mathml

On this page of my site: http://docs.gl/gl4/glBlendEquation

I have some code that looks like:

```
        <mml:math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" overflow="scroll">

            <mml:mfenced open="(" close=")">
                <mml:msub><mml:mi mathvariant="italic">R</mml:mi>
                <mml:mi mathvariant="italic">s</mml:mi>
                </mml:msub>
                <mml:msub><mml:mi mathvariant="italic">G</mml:mi>
                <mml:mi mathvariant="italic">s</mml:mi>
                </mml:msub>
                <mml:msub><mml:mi mathvariant="italic">B</mml:mi>
                <mml:mi mathvariant="italic">s</mml:mi>
                </mml:msub>
                <mml:msub><mml:mi mathvariant="italic">A</mml:mi>
                <mml:mi mathvariant="italic">s</mml:mi>
                </mml:msub>
            </mml:mfenced>
        </mml:math>
```

and in other places it looks like:

```
                    <math overflow="scroll">

                        <mrow>
                            <mi mathvariant="italic">Rr</mi>
                            <mo>=</mo>
                            <mrow>
                                <msub><mi mathvariant="italic">R</mi>
                                <mi mathvariant="italic">s</mi>
                                </msub>
                                <mo>⁢</mo>
                                <msub><mi mathvariant="italic">s</mi>
                                <mi mathvariant="italic">R</mi>
                                </msub>
                                <mo>+</mo>
                                <msub><mi mathvariant="italic">R</mi>
                                <mi mathvariant="italic">d</mi>
                                </msub>
                                <mo>⁢</mo>
                                <msub><mi mathvariant="italic">d</mi>
                                <mi mathvariant="italic">R</mi>
                                </msub>
                            </mrow>
                        </mrow>
                    </math>
```

The MathML markup in the places with the namespace prefix don't work, but the ones without the prefix seem to work just fine.

I could do a find and replace and remove the mml in all of my files, but I have hundreds of files and I would prefer to fix it if I can by editing my single shared header file. Is this possible?

Comment: You say "it doesn't work" but you don't actually say what "it" is. What are you doing and how does it fail?

Comment: The math markup doesn't appear. No italics, no subscripts, no parenthasis. Look on the page under "Description" - the stuff in the paragraph doesn't work and the stuff in that table does.

Comment: You're still not saying what you are doing, e.g. "loading the file in the Mozilla v23.5 browser".

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand why that's not obvious. It's a web page, and I said it's a web page in the first line of my question. My browser is Firefox 32. Would you like me to screenshot the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use namespace prefixed elements in HTML, you must use XHTML, including serving your page with an `application/xhtml+xml` media type. Note that your page markup is, despite your doctype, not well-formed XML, so you would need to fix that.

Otherwise, browsers will use an HTML parser. The HTML parser doesn't know about namespace prefixes, it just knows that `<math>`, `<mrow>`, `<mi>` etc are MathML elements. So in that case, you *must* convert your MathML to not use prefixes.

Comment: that makes sense. I did check that the page was XHTML but didn't look into it carefully enough - I assumed it was because it said it was.